# Multiple attacks from invisible characters

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, class-feature, invisibility

How do features like [Rapid Shot](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/rapid-shot-combat---final) or Flurry of Blows or any other form of a multiple attack scenario work with an invisible character?

Let's assume that in the beginning of the turn an archer character is invisible and he/she uses a full-round action to fire 2 arrows against a character who is actively in combat against another character but unaware of the invisible character. Also the invisibility in question is not permanent and the kind of invisibility that makes you visible after an attack such as [Invisibility](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/i/invisibility).

Is the attacked character denied his/her Dexterity bonus against both attacks or does the invisibility end immediately after the first attack and making the second attack from rapid shot or flurry of blows a normal one?

Comment: I think the more interesting question is "what happens with two weapons at the same time". Can I swing with two swords and get them both with invisibility? :)

Comment: Yeah, interesting idea, can you simultaneously attack with your two weapons? I don't have a definitive answer really.

Comment: But I don't see why you shouldn't if you're fighting with two weapons but in the case of rapid shot I think the accepted answer is sufficient.

Comment: Agreed, maybe I should ask that question as a separate question :) Maybe not a big deal for two-handed creatures, but lots of critters have full-round attacks featuring multiple limbs. A Dragon has 6 attacks from 6 different limbs :)

Comment: Yep good idea, though it's scary to think a dragon leaping out of invisibility with 6 simultaneous attacks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The archer gets visible after the first shot. So only the first one is a sneak attack.

But for example, if you have a higher initiative result at the beginning of an encounter, your foe is flat-footed and every attack you make is a sneak attack. The same is true if you flank your foe in melee.

Sometimes, you make multiple attacks with the same attack roll, such as when you use the Manyshot feat, or you make multiple attack rolls as part of the same attack, such as with the scorching ray spell. When you do so, only the first attack in the volley can be a sneak attack.